# What is the efficient way of null and empty check in setter

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, setter

I need to add null and empty checks to each of the 27 fields in my DTO class, and I'm searching for the most effective method to accomplish it. Can anyone suggest any ideas?

```
private String settingType;
private String settingCode;
private String executionEndDate;
private String startToday;
```

```
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(updateRequest.getSettingType())) {
            builder.setSettingType(updateRequest.getSettingType());
        }
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(updateRequest.getSettingCode())) {
            builder.setSettingCode(updateRequest.getSettingCode());
        }
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(updateRequest.getExecutionEndDate())) {
            builder.setExecutionEndDate(updateRequest.getExecutionEndDate());
        }
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(updateRequest.isStartToday())) {
            builder.setStartToday(updateRequest.getStartToday());
        }
```

Comment: Don’t create two classes with 27 identical properties in the first place.

Comment: If your use case is actually copying from one class to another, where both classes have similar structure (e.g. business object to/from DTO), you may want to check out something like mapstruct that does it with code generation.

Comment: I have to create 27 fields as one is for dto and the other is for proto, I need to transform data, Microservice changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use this method using consumer

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

    private <T> void setFieldIfNotEmpty(Consumer<T> setter, T value) {
        if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            setter.accept(value);
        }
    }
```

Then use the above method for null and empty check as well

```
        setFieldIfNotEmpty(builder::setSettingType, updateRequest.getSettingType());

        setFieldIfNotEmpty(builder::setSettingCode, updateRequest.getSettingCode());

        builder.setStartToday(updateRequest.getStartToday());

        setFieldIfNotEmpty(builder::setExecutionEndDate, updateRequest.getExecutionEndDate());
```

Like this

Comment: To add to the answer, you can even define `setFieldIfNotEmpty` as a static utility method and use in throughout the project, instead of it being a private member of the specific class.

Comment: Good idea, will do that

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to change methods that might return null values to instead return Optional types, e.g.:

```
Optional<String> getSettingType() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(settingType);
}
```

This has the advantage of being self-documenting (the fact that it might return no value is now explicit), and also means you can replace your code with something like this:

```
updateRequest.getSettingType().ifPresent(builder::setSettingType);
updateRequest.getSettingCode().ifPresent(builder::setSettingCode);
updateRequest.getExecutionEndDate().ifPresent(builder::setExecutionEndDate);
updateRequest.getStartToday().ifPresent(builder::setStartToday);
```

THis approach does mean creating short-lived Optional objects, so whether it's sufficiently "efficient" is something you would need to decide.

Comment: I can not change the data type. it's String settingType;

Comment: Same approach still works. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1.) It would be better to initialise some value in the constructor, So that it wouldn't got the null value for any fields.

2.) Java 8 optional would be more than beneficial for null values check.